# Input strings not correctly placed in line

Tags: perl

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 open (FILE, 'data.txt');
 open (FILE2, '>>data2.txt');
 while (<FILE>) {
 chomp;
 ($name, $email, $phone) = split("\t");
 print FILE2 "Name: $name\n";
 print FILE2 "Email: $email\n";
 print FILE2 "Phone: $phone\n";
 }
 close (FILE);
exit;
```

Here is the input file:

```
Larry larry@example.com 111-1111   
Curly curly@example.com 222-2222   
Moe moe@example.com 333-3333
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Name: Larry larry@example.com 111-1111  
Email:  
Phone:  
Name: Curly curly@example.com 222-2222  
Email:  
Phone:  
Name: Moe moe@example.com 333-3333   
Email:  
Phone:
```

The email should be on the email line and the phone number should be on the phone line.  Does anyone know why this is not working?  I apologize, I'm trying to quickly understand Perl so I can create a script that does what I need to do for my project.  I got this script from [here](http://perl.about.com/od/filesystem/a/perl_parse_tabs.htm)

Comment: Always add [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html "perldoc strict") and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html "perldoc warnings") at the beginning of your code until you know exactly why it is recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split("\t")` splits input on tabs, it looks like the fields in your input are separated by simple spaces. Instead, try one of

```
split(/ /);      # split on single space
split(/\s+/);    # split on any "whitespace" - space, tab, etc.
```

Note that the first argument to `split` is always treated as a regular expression, and for clarity you should use a regular expression instead of a string when you write a `split` call.

Comment: ($name, $email, $phone, undef) = split /\s+/, $_, 4;  ## Or is that overkill?

Comment: `split /\s+/` is almost always better written as `split`.

Comment: @JimBlack Yes that is overkill. `($name, $email, $phone) = split;` actually becomes `($name, $email, $phone) = split(' ', $_, 4);`. Just run `perl -MO=Deparse -e'($name, $email, $phone) = split'` if you don't believe me. It will also work better, as it will ignore any leading whitespace.  Also that should be `my ($name, ...`

Comment: @Brad overkill in typing only.  In my testing, performance was much better when I gave it the options (regex, scalar and limit).  Like 33% faster on average.  Could be important when looping though large files.

Comment: @JimBlack I just tested it with [Dumbbench](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dumbbench). The two examples ran in almost **exactly the same amount of time** (as expected). About the only way my code would be consistently slower is if you lexicalized the variables in mine with `my` but didn't with yours, or used the `eval` benchmarks. If you use [Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark) you should run it several times, and average the runs together to get remotely statistically useful results. Also your example won't ignore leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code.

Try adding use strict, use warnings. Then run it.

I am getting use of uninitialized variables for you phone and email variables.

```
#!usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

 open (FILE, 'data.txt');
 open (FILE2, '>>data2.txt');
 while (<FILE>) {
     chomp;
     my ($name, $email, $phone) = split(" ");
     print FILE2 "Name: $name\n";
     print FILE2 "Email: $email\n";
     print FILE2 "Phone: $phone\n";
 }
 close (FILE);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

mod has posted the correct answer, which seems to be that you are splitting on tab with space separated data. I wanted to add that this can be solved with a one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'printf "Name: %s\nEmail: %s\nPhone: %s\n", @F;' data.txt > data2.txt
```

This is simply combining the autosplit `-a` switch with a `printf`. Very simple. The code "under the hood" looks like this:

```
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    printf "Name: %s\nEmail: %s\nPhone: %s\n", @F;
}
```