# Input first non-space string

Tags: perl

I just recently asked a question here regarding reading from a file and splitting each line, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339805/input-strings-not-correctly-placed-in-line/).

Now, I have another question.  How do I make a read input read the line until a non-space/tab/whitespace character is found?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 open (ReadFrom, 'data.txt');
 open (WriteTo, '>>data2.txt');
 while (<ReadFrom>) {
 chomp;
 ($hop, $skipme, $ip, $time1) = split(/ /);
 print WriteTo "Hop: $hop\n";
 print WriteTo "IP: $ip\n";
 print WriteTo "Time: $time1\n";
 }
 close (ReadFrom);
 exit;
```

Here is an input file for example:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/QA7dyKz.png]

As you'll notice, between numbers 1 and 9, there is a space before the number, this apparently gets counted as a split and these numbers are being used as skipme values instead of hop values.  The rest (10+) are working fine since there's no space in front of the number.  What I'm looking to figure out is to ignore every whitespace character until it finds a non-whitespace character AND THEN start splitting or something.

This is the output I get with this current code:

```
Hop: traceroute
IP: www.totalnet.com.ar
Time: (200.123.156.209),
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: www.undisclosed.com
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: www.undisclosed.com
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: www.undisclosed.com
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: www.undisclosed.com
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: www.undisclosed.com
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: ae1x19.wsu5.mich.net
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: xe-4-1-1x76.eq-chi2.mich.net
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: ae-4.584.chic0.tr-cps.internet2.edu
Hop: 
IP: 
Time: xe-2-2-0.0.ny0.tr-cps.internet2.edu
Hop: 10
IP: 64.57.20.74
Time: (64.57.20.74)
Hop: 11
IP: NSS-S-A.TenGigabitEthernet8-3.ar1.EZE1.gblx.net
Time: (64.208.7.70)
Hop: 12
IP: customer-static-210-110-65.iplannetworks.net
Time: (190.210.110.65)
Hop: 13
IP: customer-static-210-110-54.iplannetworks.net
Time: (190.210.110.54)
Hop: 14
IP: customer-static-210-110-141.iplannetworks.net
Time: (190.210.110.141)
Hop: 15
IP: 190.210.125.85
Time: (190.210.125.85)
Hop: 16
IP: mx.radioelectron.com.ar
Time: (200.123.156.209)
```

Comment: You get this behaviour because you split on a regex with a space `/ /` and not a literal space `' '`, which is almost like `/\s+/`, except that it strips leading whitespace.

Comment: Also, input like that is not always suitable for parsing. On the other hand, there's often a module that does the job. I found this, for example: [`Net::Traceroute`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3ATraceroute).

Comment: These are the little things that I will have to learn and read more about when I get time. However, at this point, I'm in a hurry with something and keep having to come here.  I really appreciate your help TLP, it does work.  I hope this is the last of bothering you guys with ultra-simple questions (I'm completely new to perl, but very experienced with programming).  And yeah, I saw there is a module, but we'll see, that might be a better option, but we've already collected hundreds of traceroute and ping results, I just needed a script to get a customized analysis among them all.

Comment: Create a post with your answer so I can checkmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer per request.

You get this behaviour because you split on a regex with a space `/ /` and not a literal space `' '`, which is almost like `/\s+/`, except that it strips leading whitespace.

Also, input like that is not always suitable for parsing. On the other hand, there's often a module that does the job. I found this, for example: [`Net::Traceroute`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTraceroute).